# JAX-RS resource as POJO vs CDI vs EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, ejb, cdi

A JAX-RS root resource is defined by a `@Path` annotation and might use managed components for doing the actual work, for example:

```
@Path("resource")
public class Resource
{
  @Inject
  Worker worker;

  @GET
  public String getDetails() {
    return worker.getDetails();
  }
}
```

Now I can transfer this JAX-RS root resource to either a CDI bean:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("resource")
public class Resource {...}
```

Or to an EJB:

```
@Stateless
@Path("resource")
public class Resource {...}
```

So - what are the consequences of doing it the POJO, the CDI or the EJB way? From the outside, a request to the URL delivers three times the same thing, but what happens under the hood and how do the injected components relate to each case?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to also make this JAX-RS class an EJB or explicit CDI managed bean?

Comment: @Kukeltje: For example because of capabilities provided by managed components, like transaction, pooling, management. And in general to define a transaction border.

Comment: I always put those on services, not on front-end classes. I keep those clean/simple (in my case both my jax-rs and jsf), but there might be good reasons to combine things which I never realized.

Comment: @Kukeltje not everyone uses spring.  if he's inside an EE container, 95% of what spring provides is pretty much obsolete (other than add on modules like spring-batch, etc).  his question has merit.  ultimately, it comes down to context.

Comment: @him: 
I'm not using spring, never did, never going to. All ejb and cdi for me. 'Separation of concerns'... services in that sense. I have no clue you'd think I was talking about spring

Comment: @kukeltje i have found that when devs mention putting someting in a "service" that smells of spring (@Service annotation).  apologies if i misinterpreted your reference.  cheers!

Comment: @him: Apologies not needed ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It pretty much comes down to context. Do you need the extra facilities that an EJB provides (well defined transaction semantics, proxied stateless pooled handlers, cluster support, etc.), or do you just need dependency injection?

Just using a CDI bean will give you that off the shelf, if that's all you need. If you don't even need that, a POJO will provide your simplest bang for the buck.